# How to import Transformers with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transformer-model

After installing Transformers using

```
pip install Transformers
```

I get version 4.25.1 , but when I try to import Transformer by

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Transformer
# or
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental  import Transformer
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Transformer' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers'
```

I am using `Tenserflow 2.10` and `python 3.7`.

Comment: When you run `pip install transformers`, you are installing the transformer library from [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/). So it is not a part of the TensorFlow library. You can import it like `import transformers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have installed Transformers directly you would have to directly import transformers, as in

```
import transformers
```